# Oldschool house orchestral hit sample

Tags: sound-design, sound, synthesizer, sample

I've for a very long time been captivated by a quite memorable orchestral hit sound, which most often can be found in old House/Techno songs, probably prevalent in the early-to-mid-90s.

The hit sound I'm referring to can be heard in the fourth song on this EP, starting at 4:59, and it demarcates the jam throughout.

Is it perhaps a classic vintage synth sound? How would one attempt to recreate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is an orchestral hit / orchestral pad.

Very popular throughout the 80's

Those sounds were mostly created using the Fairlight CMI.

I think you can find a sample library or something.

I really don't know how someone should go on about creating one. But those who used them , used the Fairlight(mostly).

Comment: Thanks for laying my wondering to rest :) +1 for great video.

Comment: Hey no problem :)

Comment: Great piece of history, really enjoyed learning this, thanks @frcake

Comment: @SimonBosley , hey man , glad you enjoyed it! Pleasure's mine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find and use this sound, you could look for an old Roland General MIDI sound module.

I used an **SC-55** and later a **JV-1080** and found nice derivates of this sound, called **Orchestra Hit** on both of them.

I think, I hear the sampled versions from Roland and other manufactures more often in the 90s dance music than its old sources from fairlight.

Answer (score 1):

Also on the Korg M1, Ala Jimmy Jam and Terry Lewis Rhythm Nation era